# Import legacy PostgreSQL to a Hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've inherited an old PostgreSQL database which was built and maintained by hand. I'm now trying to bring it into JPA.

Using IntelliJ I was able to auto generate the entities but I can't seem to use them through a `JpaRepository` as it always throws `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "email" does not exist`

My entity

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Email {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "default", nullable = false)
    private boolean isDefault;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account accountByUserId;

}
```

And trying to access it through

```
public interface EmailRepository extends JpaRepository<Email, Integer> {}
```

With my hibernate settings as such

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

This is just an email entity, but I have hundreds more of which all throw the same error. Is the configuration just wrong?

Comment: Check: 1. Connection string. Are you in the right database. 2. Schema 3. Access rights of your db user. Have you granted them select rights? 4. Postgres table names are case sensitive.

Comment: In addition to what Lesiak said, you can use Table annotation to match db.table_name and your entity class-name.